# Chartkick.js how to remove x and y lines

Tags: javascript, charts, chartkick

I have simple chart made with chartkick.js (http://chartkick.com/) - not in ruby. I just want to delete X and Y lines. Doesn't matter how.

I want remove lines which I marked with red color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXWOE.png)

This is my code :
`<script>
new Chartkick.LineChart("wykres-1", {"1":0,"2":20,"3":65,"4":120,"5":280,"6":370}, {"max": 370});
</script>`

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328562/rails-4-removing-grid-lines-chartkick

Comment: This is advice for rails.

Comment: I know. But the solution they give is to make the lines transparent... So you can just make the lines transparent (lineColor: 'transparent').

Comment: Could you help me with taht?

This is my code :
<script>     
new Chartkick.LineChart("wykres-1", {"1":0,"2":20,"3":65,"4":120,"5":280,"6":370}, {"max": 370});
</script>

Comment: I don't know where I should write this line.